# How to exclude a certain word in regex?

Tags: regex, cpu-word

I'm using this expression and it's perfect for what I need:

```
.*(cq|conquest).*
```

It returns any word/phrase/sentence/etc. with the letters 'cq' or the word 'conquest' in it. However, from those matches I want to exclude all that contain the term 'conquest power'.

Examples:

- `some conquest here` (*should* match)
- `another cq with some conquest here` (*should* match)
- `too much cq or conquest power is bad` (*should not* match)

How can I do that to the regex above? It has to be only one regex otherwise the program that I'm using (Advanced Combat Tracker) will create two different tabs.

Comment: Maybe `(?!.*power).*(cq|conquest).*`

Comment: Please be more specific about what you want to exclude and what not. You state that you want to exclude the word "power" and give an example for it ("conquest power") but [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305117/how-to-exclude-a-certain-word-in-regex#comment21603979_15305391) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305117/how-to-exclude-a-certain-word-in-regex#comment21604092_15305391) you state that you only want to exclude the exact term "conquest power".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match any string which contains `"conquest"` or `"cq"`, but not if the string contains `"conquest power"`, then the regex is

```
^(?!.*conquest power).*?(?:cq|conquest).*
```

The above will attempt to match from the start of the string to the end of the line, if you want to match from the start of each line, switch on multiline mode if available - adding `(?m)` to the start of the regex may do that.

If you want to match across newlines change `.` to `[\s\S]`, or switch on `singleline` mode if available.

You have confused people by stating *"I want to match 'cq' or 'conquest'"* but also *"I want the regex to extract that line"*.

I assume you don't really want to match just "cq" or "conquest", you want to match strings/lines (?) *containing* "cq" or "conquest".

Comment: @raypixar Okay, but that regex does not meet the requirement that the string must contain "cq" or "conquest".

Answer (score 0):

From your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15305117/1) I got that you want to match all strings which contain "cq" or "conquest" but do not contain "power". For this case the following regexp works:

```
^([^p]|p(?!ower))*(cq|conquest)([^p]|p(?!ower))*$
```

([regexpal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%28[%5Ep]|p%28%3F!ower%29%29*%28cq|conquest%29%28[%5Ep]|p%28%3F!ower%29%29*%24&input=some%20sentence%20with%20cq%20and%20powerstuff%0Aanother%20sen-power-tence%20with%20conquest%20and%20stuff%0Asome%20poweer%20with%20conquest%20or%20cq%20and%20so%20on))

Comment: I want to match 'cq' or 'conquest' but if the phrase is 'conquest power' then I don't want the program that I'm using (ACT) to extract the line.

Comment: @EdgeTrio Yes, the regexp in my answer does that. Try the regexpal url to play around with some examples.